# How to get a list of connected clients in a server using Python epoll

Tags: python, sockets, client, server-side, epoll

I would like to send a message to a subset of clients connected to a server which uses Python epoll. Is there a practical way of getting list of `fileno`'s of connected clients?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be writing this (whatever it is) yourself around `select.epoll` instead of using some higher-level library like, e.g., `twisted`?

Comment: Thanks @abarnert. I wouldn't like to use `twisted` for performance reasons.

Comment: What performance reasons? You really think you can build a server from scratch better than they have? Or better than `gevent`? For that matter, do you have any good reason to believe that they're not fast enough for whatever your purpose is? If you don't really know what you're doing, there are a ton of ways you can blow your scalability/performance with a server, much worse than the cost of the few layers of abstraction `twisted` adds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the way you handle this is to keep track of the clients yourself. Every time you accept a new client, before adding it to the `epoll`, also add it to your collection. Every time you drop a client, remove it from your collection.

The typical minimal thing to store is a `dict` mapping sockets to whatever else you need to keep track of. You can use the `socket` itself, a `weakref` to it, or its `fileno` as the key. The data you need often includes things like a read buffer and a write buffer, the peer address (as received on `accept`), a name or user ID or auth cookie, etc.

And I'm not sure how you're doing anything useful with a polling server that doesn't have at least a read buffer attached to each client socket. What do you do when you get a partial message? (For that matter, if you're planning to send a message to these clients, and you don't have a write buffer, how are you going to do that?)

---

But to answer your specific question:

There is no way to get a list of fd's from a Python [`epoll` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#epoll-objects), because there is no way to do this with [the underlying API](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll).

Conceivably, you could write something that steps through everything from 0 to your max open fd and tries to do an `epoll_ctl` with it and distinguish based on the error. This is probably a very bad idea, but it may not be impossible. You'd probably have to `ctypes` down to the native function, and you may need to play around with different possibilities to find out what has the right effect. For example, maybe if you do `epoll_ctl(my_epoll.fileno(), EPOLL_CTL_MOD, fd, NULL)`, you'll get `ENOENT` for a unregistered fd, `EBADF` for a nonexistent fd, but `EINVAL` (because of the NULL `event`) for a valid fd. Or maybe it'll segfault. I can't guarantee there's any combination of parameters that will distinguish, but with some trial and error, you might find one.

(By the way, there's nothing that says that an `epoll` has to be a list of connected clients; e.g., it may be the connected clients plus the listener socket plus a "quit" pipe.)